# Reverse engineering a thread

Tags: cad, 3d-printing, threads

I have a thread in an actual product, that I want to replicate in a 3d print.

I have no clue on what to measure, and how to replicate it.

This is the thread:
[image]

One possible solution is this: I have an `openscad` script called `metric_iso_screw.scad` that it creates threads. However, it has many functions and I don't know which one is suitable for this kind of thread.

EDIT: Picture used for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Measure four things:

1. the pitch ie distance moved in one turn, or one thread to the next
2. outer thread diamter
3. inner thread diameter
4. angle of thread or between the faces: often 60 degrees

But consider just cutting the thread after the part is produced, likely stronger.

Comment: as the reference is to the metric version of creating threads, the appropriate (easier) reference on 1. is to use the thread spacing. I wonder about cutting threads in plastic being stronger. I've not seen any structured testing on YouTube regarding such an approach. It could be a useful focus.

Comment: @fred_dot_u the software mentioned metric but the picture does not provide any info about the thread - even looks like the profile is flattened. So metric may be an assumption?

Comment: I agree that it's an assumption. If the desired thread is SAE/Imperial and the code being used is metric, there is trouble afoot.

Comment: I edited my question with a picture. 1. Is what you refer as `outer diameter`, what is called as `major diameter` in the picture and what you refer as `inner diameter` as what is called `minor diameter` in the picture? 2. How exactly do I measure the `angle of thread`? 3. What do you mean by `consider cutting the thread after the part is produced, likely stronger`? Thank a lot!

Comment: I don't even know what metric is.... I just found this openscad script that makes threads..... Metric vs flattened, I don't know the difference..... This is my first time dealing with CAD.

Comment: I used "outer" and "inner" to try to be clearer - the minor diameter is also called the root diameter for  many engineers... As for the angle then gauges are available as some threads have angles of 55 or 45 or 47.5 degrees depending on function. But you could measure base and height and calculate... all those triangles form school...

Comment: Metric is the measurement system based on the **meter** and **gram** as basic units of measure and prefixes such as **milli-**, **kilo-**, **mega-**, etc., as multipliers. It has nothing to do with whether or not the thread is flattened. The alternative to metric is the **Imperial** system using inches and pounds.

Comment: `But consider just cutting the thread after the part is produced, likely stronger`. How exactly can I cut the thread afterwards? What tools are being used? Lathe? Are there handheld tools for this? How can I make sure that the right thread is cut (the 4 paramters you mentioned in your answer). Finally, what tolerances should be used? Meaning how much bigger should the original surface be from the thread (after subtraction of the material)?

Comment: Inner and outer threads have been cut by hand by using taps and dies. The dies have a slit so that they can be controlled to cut a slightly smaller thread onto a shaft depending on the tolerance of the tapped component.

Comment: So for outer threads like these, the tool that I want is called a "die"? I am non-native English speaker.

Comment: How can I know the  type of die that I want for this given thread? Trial and error?

Answer (score 2):

If you have any bolts of known thread then offer them up side by side and engage the threads to check for a match. Then you've got the pitch at least. If it's metric then you're probably looking at M10, M12, etc. and you can determine that from the outer diameter.

See https://engineeringtoolbox.com/metric-threads-d_777.html.